# Send file bytes inside object through socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I've been trying to get this working for a few days now, but I've had no success.

I want to send a file over socket client/server. The only difference is: I want to send an object that **contains** the file bytes.

So the client loads a file, reads chunks of **1024 bytes**, store them in a object, and send the object to the server. Since the file can be larger than 1024 bytes, I want to send the object repeatedly but with different bytes stored in them (as the buffer reads it). On the server, I want to compose the array of bytes and save it as a file.

The reason I'm using 1024 is because I want to avoid any sort of out of memory error, if the file is, let's say, 4 GB in size.

I tried doing the following on the client:

```
File file = new File("C:\\test\\test.txt");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

FileTest ft = new FileTest();
ft.setName("Testing");
int counttest = 1;

while (bis.read(bytes) > 0) {
    ft.setCounttest(counttest);
    ft.setBytes(bytes);
    oos.writeObject(ft);
    counttest += 1;
}
```

On the server:

```
int bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\test\\test2.txt"));    
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

while (true) {
    FileTest ft = (FileTest) ois.readObject();
    if (ft != null) {
        System.out.println(ft.getName());
        bos.write(ft.getBytes());
    }
}
```

So I tested sending a txt file with a sequence of numbers and the test2.txt file produced by the server came out only with the first 1024 chunk of bytes repeated twice. Also, the counttest integer never increases when received in the server.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your object implement serializable?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Never discard the number of bytes actually read by `bis.read(bytes) ` as it is highly likely over a socket that you will read less than the full bytes.

Comment: You don't need to buffer a stream if you read large blocks of bytes at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the effects of the ObjectOutputStream's attempt to preserve object identity.  Repeatedly writing the same object instance will result on the *same* instance on the receiver's end.  This is generally a good thing, but confusing if you are modifying the object on the sender's end and expecting those modifications to show up on the receiver's end.

Thus, you have two issues:

1. In order to send the data each time, you either need to create a new FileTest instance each time, or use the `writeUnshared()` method.
2. Due to this identity preserving behavior, you will need to periodically `reset()` the ObjectOutputStream in order to keep all these instances from being held forever (and potentially leading to an OOME on the client or server).

Comment: +1 You can use `.reset()` or `.writeUnshared(ft);` to avoid this however, I would avoid using ObjectOutputStream at all. I would use a DataOutputStream which will be more efficient, but also simpler.

Comment: Instantiating a new FileTest object worked. However, the output file still has the first 1024 bytes repeated twice (the original file is 2K). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @rodd - among other things, you need to take account of the value returned by the `read()` method.

Comment: bos.write(ft.getBytes(), 0, ft.getCount()); Didn't work, could you please explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: I just checked and server is receiving the sames bytes as before, even though the client is sending new bytes and instantiating a new object in the loop. How can I make sure that different bytes are received?

Comment: Ok, so I've added the reset() method in the end of the loop and it's all working fine. Thanks.